# PHP error: unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) on line 2

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, variable-assignment

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why I am receiving an error for this piece of PHP code? From what I have been taught, this is the correct method of writing and then reading from arrays in PHP5, but I am very confused as to why the error is occurring. I have tried to research this, but I fail to see an explanation. Thank you for your time.

The error is in this piece of code:

```
<?php
$sportsEquipment = $array(
  "Sports Shoes" => "50.22",
  "Hocky Stick" => "80.00",
  "Tennis balls" => "5.66");
echo "<pre>";
foreach($sportsEquipment as $key=>$val) {
   printf("%-20s%20.2f\n", $key, $val);
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The error message is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) on line 2

Comment: Try $sportsEquipment = array(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this you have put $array instead of array

```
$sportsEquipment = array(
  "Sports Shoes" => "50.22",
  "Hocky Stick" => "80.00",
  "Tennis balls" => "5.66");
echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: Well, don't I look like an idiot? :P

Comment: Happens No Problem Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sportsEquipment = $array(
```

should be

```
$sportsEquipment = array(
```

Basically php is seeing $array( as a function invocation whose name is defined by the value of the variable $array.  Arrow notation is not valid within a function hence the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Array literals are declared *without* leading `$` sign. You're starting with the syntax for a variable function call, not an array declaration.